# Why is there an extra & unwanted element @ the end of the list, when I attempt to group_concat & display as a column?

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

In my mysql query below, there are muliple elements (staName, separated by commas) that belong to an appointment. That is for eg, multiple staff may hold the appointment 'Teaching'.

My question is:
Why is there an extra & unwanted element or elements cut off @ the end of the list, when I attempt to group_concat & display 'staName'? I cannot get the right output, no matter how I group them. How do I rectify it?

Example erroneous output @ the end of column 'staName':
Cham Tat Sing, Norma

Correct output should be:
Cham Tat Sing, Norman Freeman       OR
Cham Tat Sing

Here is my attempt:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000;

SELECT a.appointment, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sta.staName) AS staName 
FROM staff AS sta 
INNER JOIN appointment AS a 
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.appointmentID, sta.appointmentID) > 0 
GROUP BY a.appointmentID
```

Here is my expected outcome,

where there is only 1 unique staName @ appointmentIDs 1 to 6,

multiple & all staNames (includes staName @ appointmentIDs 1 to 6) @ appointmentID 7:

```
appointmentID   |  appointment         |  staName
1                  Chair                  A          
2                  Associate Chair        B
3                  Academic               C
4                  Welfare                D
5                  Assistant              E
6                  Store                  F
7                  Teaching               A,B,C,D,E,F,G...
```

Comment: It seems you don't know what [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) does. The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) could help you understand.

Comment: Dear sir please guide me. this is the closest i can get, despite reading through the docs. I have been on this for hours, & cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: It's not clear for me what is the expected outcome. For each value of `appointment.appointmentID`, your query produces a single row (because of `GROUP BY`) that contains in field `staName` all the values of `staff.staName` that are associated with that appointment (because of the join clause), joined with comma (because of `GROUP_CONCAT()`). If this is not what you want then remove `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` (but keep `staName` in `SELECT`), run the query, check the result and continue to work on the query from there.

Comment: There can be two reasons for the last element from `staName` being truncated. It happens if you `INSERT` the result produced by this query into another table and the value of `staName` is longer than the field of the destination table can store. It also happens that the result of  `GROUP_CONCAT()` is, by default, truncated to `1024` characters. The limit is stored in variable [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) and it looks like on your server it is smaller. Or you try to use it to force the result you want?

Comment: Dear Sir I apologize for the missing info. I have updated the qn. how do i access this group_concat_max_len? there were no problems with other similar queries which gave me correct results so Ive no idea what went wrong really.

Comment: if the truncate rly happened, how do i alter the length?

Comment: You can check it's current value using `SELECT @group_concat_max_len;`. You can change it using `SET`.

Comment: dear sir u are right, the max data length of 1024 is reached & thats y the truncation. for eg, how do I set it please? have already went through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation of `GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)? Everything I've told you here I read from that page. :-)

Comment: as in i tried to execute the set statement within the query, but do not know how to go about it. instead as advised in other links, i did the SET as a separate query before executing the statement, but still it doesnt work :(

Comment: please see edit, as per your suggestion.

Comment: Dear sir thank you, it was intensive but still i got it @ the php side, on top of mysql. upvote!

Comment: Indeed, you have to run two distinct `MySQL` queries. `SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000;` needs to be run only once per session (script execution); it sets a system variable and its effect persist until you close the session (at script's end). You run the other one (the `SELECT`) how many times you want to gather the information you need from the database. I appreciate you read the documentation pages I suggested and find the answer yourself. You are on the right path.